# Extracting Nested Catch Blocks in Java Code

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to extract all catch blocks from java code. I am able to extract normal try-catch block, but if catch blocks are nested in some other types of blocks such as "if", my code is to able to detect them.

Following is the code I have written using AST parser:

```
public static void methodVisitor(String content)
{
    ASTParser metparse = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    metparse.setSource(content.toCharArray());
    metparse.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
    Block block = (Block) metparse.createAST(null);

    block.accept(new ASTVisitor()
    {
        public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment var)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(SimpleName node)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(IfStatement myif)
        {
            System.out.println("myif=" + myif.toString());
            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(TryStatement mytry)
        {
            System.out.println("mytry=" + mytry.toString());
            List catchClauses = mytry.catchClauses();

            CatchClause clause = (CatchClause) catchClauses.get(0);
            SingleVariableDeclaration exception = clause.getException();
            Type type = exception.getType();

            System.out.println("catch=" + catchClauses.toString());

            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(CatchClause mycatch)
        {
            System.out.println("mycatch=" + mycatch.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This code is not able to extract catch clause in following conditions:

```
if (base != null && base.getClass().isArray())
{
    context.setPropertyResolved(base, property);
    try
    {
        int idx = coerce(property);
        checkBounds(base, idx);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to extract nested catch blocks.
Thanks! in advance!!

Comment: "AST parser" part of what set of tools?   My guess (I don't know your tool set) is that your "visitors" are intended collectively to walk the tree, and that the "visit(IfStmt..)" returning "false" causes the tree walk to abort when the if statement is enountered.  This would prevent recursion down into the subparts of the "if" where your nested "try" clause is hiding.  Try making "vist(IfStmt...)" return "true" (it may need to call visit on its children?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess (I don't know your tool set) is that your "visitors" are intended collectively to walk the tree, and that the "visit(IfStmt..)" returning "false" causes the tree walk to abort when the if statement tree node is enountered.

This would prevent recursion down into the subparts of the "if" where your nested "try" clause is hiding.

Try making "vist(IfStmt...)" return "true" (it may need to call visit on its children?).

Comment: Hi Ira, I wanted to ask one thing. If I want to extract all the catch blocks, do I need to make visitor for all types of blocks, "if", "switch" etc.

Comment: Not my package, this was an educated guess based on how many such things work. So all I can say is, likely yes.   I think  you should go read the docs on the visitors more carefully.